# Trouble declaring object of included type

Tags: c++, constructor

If I declare an object in my header file, I get a compilation error. I can, however, construct it in my application's setup() method, simply by calling `Analyzer A(44100., "a", 200);`.

**If I construct it this way, how do I keep a pointer to it? Won't the object be inaccessible once the constructor call has gone out of scope?**

**Or, is there another way I should be getting an instance of this object?**

(What I'm used to is putting something like `Analyzer A;` in my header and then in the cpp putting `A = new Analyzer(44100., "a", 200);`. This, though, won't compile.)

Analyzer.hh:

```
class Analyzer {
  public:
    /// constructor
    Analyzer(double rate, std::string id, std::size_t step = 200);
};
```

Analyzer.cc:

```
Analyzer::Analyzer(double rate, std::string id, std::size_t step):
  m_step(step),
  m_rate(rate),
  m_id(id),
  m_window(FFT_N),
  m_bufRead(0),
  m_bufWrite(0),
  m_fftLastPhase(FFT_N / 2),
  m_peak(0.0),
  m_oldfreq(0.0)
{
/* ... */
}
```

testApp.h:

```
#include "Analyzer.hh"

class testApp : public ofSimpleApp{
public:

// *This line gives compilation error 
// "No matching function for call to Analyzer::Analyzer()"

      Analyzer A;
    }
```

testApp.cpp:

```
void testApp::setup(){

// *This line compiles, but how will I access 
//this object outside of current scope?*
  Analyzer A(44100., "a", 200);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can initialize constructor type of A 
in constructor of testApp as

```
testApp:testApp():A(44100., "a", 200){
//testApp constructor. 
}
```

Comment: *initialize*, not *define*, but this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn C++ from scratch. You're trying to bring over reference semantics from a language like Java or C# and those don't exist in C++. You need a C++ approach.

`Analyzer A;` is a value. It is constructed directly. If you use a member variable, you must construct it with the initializer list.

```
testApp::testApp()
: A( args ) {}
```

When on function local scope, traditionally you return a copy of the object, or use a self-owning smart pointer such as `shared_ptr` to hold the object. In C++, you do not resort to dynamic allocation unless you actually need a dynamic lifetime- you can alias stack-based variables if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the process of doing exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

`Analyzer A;` -> `Analyzer *A;` and `Analyzer A(44100., "a", 200);` -> `A = new Analyzer(44100., "a", 200);`